# How can I make an SVN repo searchable on a WIndows 7 machine with cygwin?

Tags: svn, search, windows-7

I have an old remote SVN repo (`https://foo.bar.com/myRepo`) that is a collection of projects each of which has branches/, trunk/ and tags/ subfolders. I need to find a file in the repo but it's quite big so clicking through each project in the SVN browser is not feasible.

The collection is frozen, i.e. I am not going to modify any of the projects.

I have tried to create a local git repo and import the whole SVN colleciton into it using `svn2git` and some other approaches that I googled up but none of them worked producing different errors.

I have a Windows 7 machine that has `cygwin` installed, inclduing `git`.

What are different (free) ways to make the SVN repo searchable? Are there freeware tools out there designed specifically for Windows and/or Windows+cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open command prompt, type `powershell`.

Then type:

```
svn list -R  https://path-to-svn/svn/test | select-string "file name or regex"
```

You can also append `> e:\result.txt` at the end of above line to get results in text file.

Note: URL to svn repo will have to include project name, otherwise, you will get HTTP 405. For example, if you have 2 projects - test and test2 in your SVN, your url must look like this: https://path-to-svn/svn/test or like this https://path-to-svn/svn/test2, you can not search both projects.

**EDIT:**

The following PS script will list all projects in your repo + search for file in those. Note that XML processing of HTTP response is included, so I am not 100% sure it will work for your SVN server without any modification.

```
powershell
$username = "user"
$password = "pass" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
$res = Invoke-WebRequest https://path-to-svn/svn/ -Credential $cred
$xdoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xdoc.LoadXml($res.Content)
foreach($href in $xdoc.SelectNodes("//dir").href) 
{  
    $svnRepo = "https://path-to-svn/svn/" + $href
    foreach ($match in svn list -R  $svnRepo | select-string "file name or regex")
    {
        Write-host  ("{0}{1}" -f $href, $match)
    }
}
```

If you copy-paste in cmd and it does not run right away, make sure you have carriage-return at the end of the script.

Comment: Thanks, the first command worked both in a regular DOS shell and in a cygwin terminal window. Do you know if there is a similar command that would list all projects under the root, i.e. both test and test2 in your example? This way I can write a simple script to get the listing of everything. Thx

Comment: Still just `svn ls`, I Z.

Comment: Ivan, does `select-string` from powershell offer benefits over the `findstr` standard with the normal cmd.exe shell in this situation?

Comment: @IZ: I have updated the script to list all projects under the root and then execute svn list on them.